# Draw 18 plots on one graph in R?

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization

I have a dataframe with 18 column and I want to see seasonally adjusted state of each variables on a single chart.

Here is head of my dataframe;

`head(cityFootfall))`

```
  Istanbul Eskisehir Mersin
1    44280     12452  11024
2    58713     13032  12773
3    21235      5629   5749
4    20934      5968   5764
5    21667      6022   5752
6    21386      6281   5920
Ankara Bursa Adana Izmir
1  19073  5098  8256 15623
2  22812  7551 10631 18511
3   8777  2260  3733  8625
4   8798  2252  3536  8573
5   8893  2398  3641  9713
6   8765  2391  3618 10542
Kayseri Antalya Konya
1    8450    2969  4492
2    8378    4421     0
3    3491    1744     0
4    3414    1833     0
5    3596    1733     0
6    3481    1785  1154
Samsun Kahramanmaras Aydin
1   4472          4382  4376
2   4996          4773  5561
3   1662          1865  2012
4   1775          1710  1957
5   1700          1704  1940
6   1876          1848  1437
Gaziantep Sanliurfa Izmit
1      3951      3752  3825
2      5412      4707  4125
3      2021      1326  1890
4      1960      1411  1918
5      1737      1204  1960
6      1833      1143  2047
Denizli Malatya
1    2742    3809
2    3658    4346
3    1227    1975
4    1172    1884
5    1102    2073
6    1171    2060
```

> 

Here is my function for this:

```
plot_seasonality=function(x){

par(mfrow=c(6,3)) 
plot_draw=lapply(x, function(x)  plot(decompose(ts(x,freq=7),type="additive")$x-decompose(ts(x,freq=7),type="additive")$seasonal)

}
plot_seasonality(cityFootfall)
```

When I run this function I get error says:  `Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large` but when I change my codes from`par(mfrow=c(6,3)` to `par(mfrow=c(3,3)` its works and give me last 9 columns plot like this image[image] but I want to see all variable in a single chart

Could anyone help me about solve my problem?

Comment: reduce the margins - `par(mar = c(3, 3, .5, 0.5))` - will also need to adjust position of axis labels etc

Comment: Please provide a sample of your dataset. I assume you would like one plot with all 18 variables as a single line. This is easily done with `ggplot2`, but you must transform your dataset in a long format. Take a look at `tidyr`and the function `gather`

Comment: I think this happens because you are trying to plot the results on RStudio or a pre-specified window. Have you tried to use `pdf()` function and then run your code with `par(mfrow=c(6,3))`?

Comment: Look at the `gridExtra` package and use `grid.arrange` instead. Works wonderfully with `ggplot`.

Comment: @OB83 I have just edited my question and add head of my dataframe. I would prefer do this with ggplot2 nicer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally your windows is not big enough to plot that:

1) open a big window with `dev.new()`, or from Rstudio `X11()` under linux or `quartz()` under MacOSX)

2) simplify your ylab that will free space

```
# made up data
x <- seq(0,14,length.out=14*10)
y <- matrix(rnorm(14*10*6*3),nrow=3*6)

# large window (may use `X11()` on linux/Rstudio to force opening of new window)
dev.new(width=20,height=15)
par(mfrow=c(6,3))

# I know you could do that with `lapply` but don't listen to the fatwas 
# on `for` loops it often does exactly the job you need in R
for(i in 1:dim(y)[1]){
    plot(x,y[i,],xlab="Time",ylab=paste("variable",i),type="l")
}
```

You should also consider plotting several variables in the same graph (using `lines` after an initial `plot`).

[image: All 18 graphs together]

Comment: thanks.your answer solved my problem.In addition this I want to make better look plot with ggplot2. Do u think Could I run this function using ggplot2 easily? Any Thoughts? @cmbarbu

Comment: Yes you can use ggplot2 plotting functions in spite of plot in the function but I'm no expert of ggplot. If you have an issue, check other similar questions using ggplot and if nothing satifying ask your own.

Comment: @cmarbu. I have one more question.The plots are very small in a graph. Is there any chance make them bigger.I know there is a 18 variable to draw plot and its too much. I thought if we can make scrolling chart window maybe plots looks bigger. Any Thoughts? Thanks in advance

Comment: @OzgurAlptekın just make a much higher window and save it then in a pdf. Add at the end: `dev.print(pdf,file="myExample.pdf")`. You can then scroll this page in any pdf viewer.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested: transform data in long format with package `tidyr`, see function `gather`:

I added a time variables since it was missing.

```
temp <- cityFootfall %>% transform(time = 1:nrow(temp)) %>% gather(variable, key, -time)
```

Now plot it with `ggplot2`(default settings, you can adjust this like you want)

```
gplot(temp, aes(x = time, y = key, group = variable, color = variable)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]